# Imagemagick: green screen mask (circus face hole)

Tags: imagemagick

I would like to know if it is possible to get a green screen mask from a picture.

I try to explain: I have a photo with a human body with a green screen in the background, now I don't want to remove the green screen in order to obatin the person's body but the opposite.

I need to get the green screen as mask in order to use it as example for other body photos that have to match this mask like a "circus face hole".

Sorry for my english

Thanks.

Comment: What have you tried? A very simple green screen mask can be created by `a = K1 * (r + b) - K2 * g` where K1&K2 are constants -- usually 1.0.

Comment: At the moment I'm not developing it (I can't), it's a question about feasibility and how.
Thanks for your answer.

Comment: I do not understand your question. Please post an example image of what you have and what you want.

Comment: @fmw42 unfortunately I don't have an example because it's just a pre-sell at the moment. I try to explain in a different way: we usually have a green screen in order to get the shape of a figure without the background. In my case I want the opposite, I want to get ONLY the background (green screen)  in order to use it as an overlay mask. I need this because this overlay mask must "force" a second, third etc. photo to stay in the borders of that mask. The circus hole example is the best I can show you.

Answer (score 0):

In ImageMagick, I make every color but green into transparent. Then I extract the alpha channel as your mask.

`convert image -fuzz XX% +transparent greencolor -alpha extract mask.png`

Set an appropriate XX% between 0 and 100 to catch all the green color. If it is constant, then use 0 or a low value. Specify your exact green color if it is constant or some reasonable green color if not constant and increase the fuzz value. The result will be white where you have green and black elsewhere.

So for example:

Input:

[image]

```
convert greenscreen.jpg -fuzz 15% +transparent "rgb(4,160,67)" -alpha extract mask.png
```

[image]